# Is French Suit French?

Tags: word-usage

I've been trying to find an answer to this question and found an article by Grammar Girl [where she wrote about capitalizing the 'french' in french fries](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/should-you-capitalize-the-french-in-french-fries). She quotes CMoS as follows:

> 'The Chicago Manual of Style [also] recommends keeping french
>   lowercase because french isn’t being used to literally refer to the
>   country.'

Even though she was writing about *french fries*, I believe this is a rule of thumb which applies to all such usage. So, I needed to find the origin of F/french suits so I can determine whether they literally originate or have to do with France. After a google search, I still haven't been able to ascertain the origin of F/french suits.

So, question is, which of these would be correct?

> He wore a blue French suit.
>
> He wore a blue french suit.

Comment: the usage according to Ngram seems to be with a capital F, no hit with f wathsoever in Ngram or Google Books. As it stands, if you want to conform to current standards, use "French suit"

Comment: What @P. Obertelli said ([here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+french+suit%2Ca+French+suit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20French%20suit%3B%2Cc0) the relevant chart).

Comment: But I don't know what OP's ***blue*** French suit refers to. I only know the collocation in the context of the "pip" designs on playing cards - [*most popular of which is the French suit which we use these days. In french suit **coins** turned into **diamonds**, the **cups,** which stood for “love”, turned into **hearts**, **swords** turned into **spades**, **sticks** turned into **clubs.***](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-the-four-suits-of-a-standard-deck-of-playing-cards-spades-hearts-diamonds-and-clubs) Where *that* writer capitalized inconsistently!

Comment: Then you'll be intrigued to know it refers to men's clothing!

Comment: @user191110: That much is obvious, but I don't suppose one in a thousand native speakers would know how to differentiate a *French* suit from any other kind of suit. And I couldn't easily find a definition by Googling.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree.  I think the best way to look at this is the other way round, almost:  that French should generally speaking always be capitalized, but if something is used enough in a broader context it sometimes loses its proper noun status and that's what's happened with "french fries": ie, it has **evolved** to lose its capital letter.

Comment: I've come across 'french fries', but never 'german measles'. I'm not so sure that the CMoS recommendation isn't very niche (and probably rightly so).

Comment: Max Williams, that's not quite the reasoning behind lowercasing French fries. According to CMoS, and in particular those who agree with it, it's the cut of the fries that gives it the description 'french' rather than its evolution or origin.

Comment: Lol... auto correct to French fries not intended.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, Here's an article that explains the reason German is capitalized in German measles: 

"German measles (rubella) is one of the common rash diseases of childhood. It is called "German measles" because a German physician wrote a clear description of it in 1760." --http://www.health24.com/Medical/Childhood-diseases/Overview/German-measles-Rubella-20120721

Comment: But that doesn't explain why it shouldn't have evolved to 'german measles' in the same way that 'poinsettia' has become decapitalised. @Malvolio's answer seems doubly good in providing a reasonable explanation and pointing out how idiosyncratic the process seems to be. // I'm not convinced that _French suit_ is more than a loose collocation (at best) in the dress sense, unlike _french fries_ which is a compound (and hence a new [when coined] lexeme).

Answer (score 1):

The columnist James Kilpatrick spend [an entire column](http://community.seattletimes.nwsource.com/archive/?date=19961013&slug=2353931) trying to find some rule for deciding when eponyms retained their capitalization and when they lost it.

He found not only did such a rule did not exist but that lexicographers disagree about the proper use of such well-known words as "herculean", "stoic", and "stygian".

My guess would be that it is connected with the popularity of the named item, compared to that of the namer.  Who remembers, after all, the first US ambassador to Mexico, Joel Roberts Poinsett -- so the flower he brought back from his post is lowercased.  His fellow diplomat Vyacheslav Molotov, Stalin's foreign minister, is better known, so the improvised firebombs Finns threw at Soviet tanks are capitalized.

This shaky rule would suggest "French suit" -- since most people (myself included) have never heard of that style -- but "french fries".

Answer (score 0):

I have made a bit of progress with this and thought everyone might benefit from the answer:

Okay, so first, I search over and over for 'french suit' until I found an online store that had product pictures of certain short-sleeved suits. Although, I didn't see the words 'french suit' there, I realized they must be the short-sleeved suits on there.

So I did another search with the question: '[Is safari suit same as french suit?](https://www.google.com/search?q=is%20safari%20suit%20same%20as%20french%20suit%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab)' That was where I found [this](https://whatcanilearntoday.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/who-invented-the-safari-suit/) and [this](http://www.smh.com.au/news/obituaries/french-poet-of-couture-fathered-safari-suit/2009/01/05/1231003933761.html) websites which throw more light on the relationship between safari and french suits (because I wondering if the inventor of safari suits was French).

Indeed, he was a man by the name of Ted Lapidus, aka the ‘poet of French couture’!

Whodunit solved!